# Application Architechture MVC,MVVM etc

Tags: model-view-controller, mvvm, architecture, mvp

Architecture patterns like `MVC`,`MVVM`, `MVP` are only used in presentation tier?. 
Can we use in Business Logic layer or Data access layer?
 I previously thought that `Presentation Tier` is `View`;
`BusinessLogic Tier` is `Controller/Viewmodel` and `Data Access Layer` is `Model`. 
please someone clarify this..

Answer (score 1):

The patterns you mention provide concepts to couple business and presentation tier. Considering a classical three tier architecture with the tiers you've mentioned: *Data Access Layer*, *Business Logic*, *Presentation Layer*, then `MVVM`, `MVC`, `MVP` provide concepts for the coupling of *Presentation Tier* and *Business Logic*. As the main idea is a loose coupling between the two to avoid logical dependencies between the two layers as much as possible, I would think of them as a kind of mediator (in the meaning of the word, not the pattern) or glue between them.

Let me clarify this for MVVM, exemplary:

You can write a complete presentation tier in WPF without utilizing `MVVM`. Just as well you can write the business logic without knowing the concept of `MVVM`. You don't need ViewModels at all to build a working application.

But: You have no chance to cleanly separate the concerns of presentation/UI and the actual logic which performs the tasks your software has been written for. The border between the two is kind of fuzzy in the real world: You calculate data, now you want to transform the data to display it in a diagram. Is this business logic? Yes and no. Is this UI logic? Yes and no. There's a grey zone: Kind of logic, kind of UI. This is where `MVVM` (and the like) kick in: You add a layer between business and presentation which is dedicated to this grey zone only.

For MVVM: The View is the View, it's the *presentation layer*. And the ViewModel is the *grey zone*, which is neither real Presentation, nor real business logic, but the glue between them. The Model is the model, it's the *business logic*. It could even be written without knowing that it will be used in a WPF application (theoretically). And there can be business logic, which is not even a model in the MVVM meaning, because it is not UI related at all.

Below this, comes everything else with the *DAL* at the bottom. The *DAL* should really not care about how business logic and presentation are glued together and is beyond the scope of the discussed patterns.

Comment: *[...] The Model is the model, it's the business logic. [...]* - Uhm, no the model is data and only data. Well yes you should have possibilty to load the data, but therefore usually you don't need a sophisticated logic. Pls, have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090102).

Comment: *[...] And the ViewModel is the grey zone, which is neither real Presentation, nor real business logic, but the glue between them. [...]* - Nope, the VM is the business logic which reflects its state in properties. The view interprets these properties to visualize it.

Comment: Well IMHO patterns are nothing about religion. It's all about talking with the same language. If you talk to another developer and you both have your own interpretation of the same pattern...well it'll lead to a mess. So either you stick to MVVM or you don't, but then you shouldn't call it so. ;o)

Comment: @DHN Feel free to post an answer, I am not interested in discussing subjective things in comments. And believe me, it is subjective as the points you are making are referring to the term *business logic*, which is extremely unsharp. End of my contribution at this point.

Comment: Business logic - *extremly unsharp*, well interesting opinion. At least it's difficuilt to find a specific definition, which is not related to a certain part of software development. But you're right. Let's stop the discussion. I won't write an own answer, since I totally agree with the first part of your post, which covers exactly the issue. I only disagree with *your interpretation* of `Model` and `ViewModel`.

Comment: @DHN It could be an interesting discussion in real life. Some day, maybe ;) Cheers, mate.

Comment: Yeap, would be great. ;o) Cheers

Comment: @Marc "Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern splits the User Interface code into 3 conceptual parts ". I have refered following article.[link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/278901/MVVM-Pattern-Made-Simple).According to this MVVM deals only with presentation tier..

Comment: MVVM is definitely not only presentation tier. I've described what MVVM is in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Architecturally, I would say that `MVC`, `MVP` and `MVVM` is the presentation tier. The point of view between each components are:

1. View

   This is very clear that it belongs to presentation layer. Not discussion about this
2. Controller / Presentation / View Model

   If you take off the N-Tier principal, this is the business tier. Seems like this design pattern were invented without taking any coupling with the N-Tier.

   `Controller` has Session and HttpContext utilization. It is web dependent. According to N-Tier principal, the BLL must not know any UI. Therefore it goes for presentation tier.

   `Presentation` has events / event handlers / delegations and some UI-specific data. (CMIIW, I'm not too fluent with MVP). Therefore it goes for presentation tier.

   As other said, `ViewModel` is rather hard to be classified as presentation tier. However, I find it better to put into presentation tier. In my experience using WPF, sometimes I need to use MVVM specific objects like `ObservableCollection` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `ICommand` to force data binding refresh. Sometimes it is needed for the `ViewModel` to access custom session state, such as login, etc. Other times, you need to specify some UI-specific parameter such as font color, etc. This may be avoided by handling the logic in View, however I find it is easier to do it in ViewModel.

   Another thing to consider, using MVVM prevent me to use Service - Repository pattern.
3. Model

   If you take the N-Tier off from MV- pattern, this is the entity model. It is described at Asp.Net MVC, where the model will be used in the view, as the container for data. However, if you take N-Tier into account, then this is the business tier, where you do insert/update/delete operation to the data, and the logic for it resides.

Comment: @Fendy.. hi.. as far as my knowledge. all above architecture patterns are within presentation tier.Presentation tier is then devided in to another 3 tiers.Model is a set of classes representing the data coming from the services or the database.View is the code corresponding to the visual representation of the data the way it is seen and interacted with by the user.ViewModel serves as the glue between the View and the Model. It wraps the data from the Model and makes it friendly for being presented and modified by the view.

Comment: If you take off the N-Tier principle then yes. If you include it, then both `View` and `Controller` can be considered as Presentation only. For ViewModel, it is special case. Eventhough you can consider it as `glue`, I don't think it is a best place to put business logic there. I may be wrong, but my understanding it is hard to put Service-Repository design there.