# MVC - are there situations when it's either irrelevant or inappropriate?

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture, separation-of-concerns

When developing an app with GUI, and database access, are there situations where the MVC architecture isn't relevant?

To me it seems that the Views and Controllers must only be different entities is one to upgrade the views, or to replace them with something else, namely mobile displays (or predicts such a possible change for the future of the app).

Also, I see the separation of the Model and Controllers only necessary if the Model is to be upgraded / replaced.

So is there any other purpose for the MVC architecture that the situations when components should be upgraded/ changed, or is this really it?

Comment: MVC is just a tool. You may or may not use it, you may make your program to be a total mess, just it will be more complicated to maintain. The advantage comes from separation of concerns, but if one wants to put all the layers together, not using that advantage is his/her personal decision. There is no such thing as "appropriate" in architecture.

Comment: @Vlad: MVC is not a tool, it's a software architecture pattern.

Comment: @L-Three: any pattern is just a tool for the developer. You may or may not use it if you find it useful for you.

Comment: A tool helps you to implement a pattern, but is not a tool.

Answer (score 1):

I like MVC because it makes it easier to think about how different parts of the app are going to work together. If everything is just lumped in together, I find it much harder to visualise in my head.

So it's not really a case of when you should use it, rather how do you prefer to think?

If you find it easier not using MVC then you should probably not use MVC.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the root of you confusion is the scope at which you try to apply MVC design pattern.

MVC is not a pattern for small applications. Instead you are supposed to apply it, when your free-form OOP code starts to become unmanageable. Your codebase might be implementing all of the [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29), but at some point you will start getting lost there.

That would be when you should be using MVC, because this design pattern *applies additional constraints*. It does not add anything new to application. Instead it limits what code can go in what parts of your application.

> <sub>**P.S.** you also seem mistaken about what separation there is in MVC. The basic divide is between model layers and presentation layers. Those are two main parts MVC applications. And only then withing the presentation layer there is a separation between views and controllers. You might benefit from reading [**this article**](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

For me, it all comes down to testability.  Automated testing of UI code is exorbitantly expensive compared to testing of model code.  It is much easier to achieve test coverage in model and event controller layers compared to view layers.

If you have no need to test your application, and it is small enough that you can keep it all straight in your head, then MVC is probably a waste of time.  Very few applications are truly small enough that these concerns are not at issue. But if the app is truly that small, MVC will add far more overhead than it will provide in value.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of `MVC` design pattern as you business architecture. Treat `MVC` as presentation architecture. There are many arguments about `MVC` usage in terms of business architecture. This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977501/application-architechture-mvc-mvvm-etc/16983247#16983247) is one example.

Actually, you are looking for `N-Tier` architecture. Where it is separated as `DAL`, `BLL` and `PL`:

**Data Access Layer (DAL):**

A layer responsible to inteact with the Storage (insert/update/delete)

**BLL:**

A layer where the business logic resides. This layer is the core of your application. Some people often use the term Middleware (please correct me if wrong) to represent the `BLL`. BLL does not know the UI, means that it can be used by Desktop app, web app, mobile app, etc.

**PL:**

This is your presentation layer or UI layer. MVC, at least the `View` and `Controller` resides here.

Answer (score 0):

There are benefits to the MVC architecture, and there are some disadvantages to it.  You have to weigh them for your project to see which would be the most appropriate for you.

Advantages for MVC:

- More maintainable because it's compartmentalized (separation of
  concerns).
- It's more testable because you can unit test the controllers.
- You typically have more control over the HTML that gets generated
  (Yes, you can accomplish the same with webforms, but only if you give
  up all of the advantages of webforms as well).
- Your webpages will be smaller and faster because you won't be
  carrying around page/view/control state.
- Integrates better with client-side lifestyle and libraries
  (Bootstrap, jQuery and it's many plug-ins, AJAX, etc)

Advantages of webforms:

- More 3rd party controls (webforms relies heavily on either 3rd party controls, or custom usercontrols to achieve rapid application development).
- If you need viewstate, then it takes less work, but this is pretty
  rare if designed right.
- Integrates better with server side control libraries.

Of course, someone is going to say, why did you list xyz as an advantage for whatever, because you can do that in the other one too! Well, you can achieve the same thing in both frameworks, it's just a matter of ease.  What is easy for one may be more difficult in the other, but both of them, given enough time and resources can do it too.

Comment: The question asker made no mention of anything web, or html or anything else.  MVC is a design pattern used in many languages and technologies, you seem to assume he means asp.net-mvc, which I see no indication in his question that this is the case.

Comment: You are correct.  MVC is a generic term, and I misread it to be asp.net-mvc.  I'll leave the answer up because the OP is likely talking about asp.net-mvc (he has C# background), and the non-specific portions apply to MVC in general usually in comparison to other non-MVC frameworks.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say he has a C# background, nearly all of his questions he's asked have been oriented around Abap and Python.  In fact, I can't find a single C# question he's asked or answered.

Comment: I didn't check further than his profile which states `Previously: Java EE, C#`

Answer (score 0):

MVC is about **separation of concerns** and making these concerns **testable**.

Someone said 'MVC is not a pattern for small applications.'. I disagree. Why? It only dictates how you separate concerns, I don't understand why this should be different for small applications. I would argue it's even simpler because every developer uses the same pattern and is used to it. It's not overhead, it's consistency. Also look what [this guy](http://gastonnusimovich.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/we-should-always-use-mvc/) has to say.

Another thing: MVC is a presentation layer pattern (Separated Presentation), it means it logically separates your UI in a models, views and controllers. Controllers are responsible for managing the flow, interacting with the backend system to query and save data, and converting that data to models (or view models) that are used by the views.

The backend in itself is another system, which has its own independent architecture, with services, domain and data layer (as for example the onion architecture, of which an example can be found [here](http://ludwigstuyck.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/a-reference-architecture-part-1/)).